# C# adding a browse function along with a Drag and Drop box

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

So I already have a working drag and drop box that opens up a .csv file. I want to add a openfiledialog method of opening up a file as well. In my dragdrop function I have:

```
    private void panel1_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Here 1");
        firstTimeThrough = true;
        timer.Stop();

        if (browseRecordFiles == true)
        {
            files = (string[])e.Data.GetData(fileLocation, false);
        } else
        {
            files = (string[])e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop, false);
        }
```

Obviously ...GetData(fileLocation, false); cannot work here. Is there a different work around for this? I have a ForEach loop that then iterates through "files" so that's why I would like for it to work this way.

"browseRecordFiles" is a boolean that turns true if the "browse" button was clicked.

I.e.: fileLocation would be c:\users\Administrator\desktop\something.csv

Edit: I **have** a button to press to open the file dialog but then I have a ForEach Loop as shown here:

```
                foreach (string file in files)
                {

                    try
                    {
                        using (var reader = new StreamReader(file))         // reading the file
                        {
                            while (!reader.EndOfStream)             // Read until the end of the stream
                            {
                                var line = reader.ReadLine().Replace("\"", "");
                                //Console.WriteLine(line);
                                var values = line.Split(',', ' ');   // Ignore the , in the .CSV file and start next read column

                                foreach (var k in values)
                                {
                                    //Console.WriteLine(k);
                                }


                                data.Add(values);             // Add all values to data list
                            }
```

Files is a string array but only **holds** the file path of the drag and dropped file. Is there a way to "mimic" this as if the user dropped the file onto it by get the file path from the open file dialog?

Comment: Is this Windows Forms?  If so, you should tag the question with that.

Comment: `void panel1_DragDrop` is triggered when files were dropped. You need a `button_Clicked` that is triggered when the button is clicked to open a file dialog.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that this is a Windows Forms app...

1. Drop a button on your Form (or some other way for the use to signal that he wants to open a file (a File menu with an Open entry, for example)
2. Drop an `OpenFileDialog` control on your form.  It will be named `openFileDialog1`
3. In the properties of the dialog control, set the `DefaultExt` to `csv` and the `Filter` to `Comma-Separated Files|*.csv|All Files (*.*)|*.*`

   - You may want to set other properties, like the `Title`
4. Double-click on your new button, to create a button `Click` handler and open the code file to that location.
5. In the handler, put in code like this:

This is a standard Open File handler:

```
  private void OpenFileBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      //you may want to set the default `InitialDirectory` property
      if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
      {
         //do something with the information from the OpenFileDialog
         //in particular, you are going to want to read the `FileName` property
      }
 }
```

If you want the user to be able to open multiple files at a time, set the `MultiSelect` property.

To use those multiply-selected filenames, look at the `FileNames` property of the dialog.  It is a collection of filenames (full file and path names) that the user has chosen.  Iterate through that list and call `File.ReadAllText` or `File.ReadAllLines` to get the contents of the CSV files.

Comment: I have this already done. I have the filename/path from the file that was selected from the OFD but now I need to "mimic" or open it similarly to how dragdrop does it; like (string[])e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop, false);

Comment: I updated my answer with an additional paragraph.  Does that answer your question?  BTW, I answered this before you put your edit in (I think).  Using one of the `File.ReadAllXxx` calls will be easier than what you are doing to do to pull stuff from the clipboard